# 1A load with 3 1,5V@2950mAh AA Alcaline batteries

Tags: voltage, batteries, switches

I have a system that is powered with 3 AA Alcaline batteries Varta Industrial Pro (1,5V@2950mAh).

The batteries are connected to a [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22049f.pdf) 3V3 LDO that supplies power to a MCU. I have taken a minimum dropout of 150mV (so LDO would work down to 3V45).
The MCU system will activate (using a FET) a electronic lock of [this](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/33014028504.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.1.63c06b745oDfh4&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.146401.0&scm_id=1007.13339.146401.0&scm-url=1007.13339.146401.0&pvid=eebc356d-4ac6-46c4-b469-ceab248741b8&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.146401.0,pvid:eebc356d-4ac6-46c4-b469-ceab248741b8,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2312_668%23808%234094%23101_668%23888%233325%2312_668%232846%238112%23600_668%232717%237565%23707) type, which consumes a maximum of 1000mA during 1 second and admits a voltage from 3V to 5V.
As my LDO only supports up to 250mA I would like to know.

I would like to know if there would any problem connecting the lock directly to the three batteries power supply, as they are a not fixed voltage power supply.

In case there's no problem, would these three batteries in series be capable of maintaining the required voltage level when the lock is activated?

Comment: The lock admits from 3v to 5V

Comment: @jsotola My question is not about the lock maximum ratings, is about connecting the lock directly to the batteries and not using a voltage fixed power supply

Comment: @jsotola You're right. Thanks for that. I've changed the link. For some reason I put the wrong one.

Comment: it is unclear what problem you are having ... if the lock operates on a voltage between 3 V and 5 V, why would you think that 4.5 V is somehow excluded from that range?

Comment: The problem is I have never used this type of mechanisms and I don´t know if they need a fixed voltage source or what implications are there if you connect it directly to the batteries. On the other hand, if there's a voltage drop due to the load demanded by the lock, maybe the LDO will not have enough input voltage to give the 3V3 to the MCU

Comment: why would there be implications? ... just supply the required voltage ... as long as enough current is available at the provided voltage, the lock should operate ... the lock mechanism probably uses a solenoid to pull the latch ... just drive it same as a motor ... there is a lot of info on the internet about doing that

Comment: @jsotola I understand. I thought there would maybe some implications that I'm not aware of. Thank you very much

Comment: In general, to get the best life from alkaline batteries when drawing high currents you need to design for an end-point voltage of 0.9V per cell. This is just 2.7V from a 3-cell battery.

Comment: Where did you get the lock V and I specs thae ad does not seem to give them (I may have missed them). It is likely that the lock will work well enough doen to about 3.\450 V battery. A large capacitor across the battery may help. A large output cap on the LDO (if stability allows) will prevent dropout effects when battery is marginal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a much better design to connect the lock directly to the batteries, this way the lock operation will not inject current spikes or other disturbances downstream of the LDO where the MCU is connected.

When the batteries are new they will maintain the appropriate voltage level (3-5V there is ample margin). At some point when they become depleted the lock will not operate anymore and the MCU may reset if the voltage goes too low during the lock operation.

On this site, you can compare the voltage vs current of AA batteries
https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/CommonAAcomparator.php

set the current to 1A instead of the default 2A

They list some Varta models but not your specific model, but Varta should be able to supply the curves

When the battery is new enough, the voltage per cell drops with 1A drawn but is above what you need as there is a need of at least 1.15V per cell to keep the LDO working (3 x 1.15 = 3.45).

At some point during the discharge, the 1A curve crosses down the 1.15V level, the batteries will have to be replaced to maintain proper operation of the LDO + MCU.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And can the batteries support that current spike during a maximum of 1s without voltage drop?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
If you were using a switching power supplier buck/boost you can use
 3 AA Batteries maximum

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how this relates to the question

Comment: Adding slightly more explanation will help people see the relevant points you are tring to make.

Comment: You are using LDO that reduce significantly lowers battery life